# Find poetry installation used by PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, python-poetry

I am trying to set up a Poetry virtual environment in PyCharm. I am doing the following:

1. Press Ctrl+Alt+S to open the Project Settings
2. Go to Project -> Python Interpreter
3. Click on Add Intepreter -> Add Local Interpreter...
4. Select Poetry Environment
5. Select Poetry Environment
6. Make sure Python 3.11 is selected as the Base Environment
7. Click OK

This gives the following error:

> RuntimeError: The lock file is not compatible with the current version of Poetry.

I already installed poetry 1.3.2. I can confirm this from powershell:

```
PS C:\src\my-project> poetry --version
Poetry (version 1.3.2)
```

I think I have another version of poetry installed somewhere and PyCharm is picking it up. How do I find this instance of poetry? Where do I look for it?

Comment: If it is any help, I have been using Poetry with PyCharm and I did not even know it has native support for Poetry. I have always used option "Virtual environment" for the Python installation and then point it to `python` command in `venv` created by Poetry. Thus if you want to have a workaround try "normal" virtual environment option in PyCharm.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa Thanks for the tip. So I assume you are suggesting that I run poetry commands from the command line, right?

Comment: Yes. Poetry is still young and rapidly evolving, so I would be surprised if PyCharm can offer stable support.